# How to get native source code of send a mail in andorid?

Tags: android

I am new to android.

I want to get the native source code of send email.

For example in our android we have a icon like email.

Then any one click the email icon the mail application will open.

so I want that source code.

Comment: u can try from this [link][1] hope it helps.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-android-ap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the step to create project..

```
YOUR PACKAGE;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MailSenderActivity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final Button send = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.send);
        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                try {   
                    GMailSender sender = new GMailSender("username@gmail.com", "password");
                    sender.sendMail("This is Subject",   
                            "This is Body",   
                            "user@gmail.com",   
                            "user@yahoo.com");   
                } catch (Exception e) {   
                    Log.e("SendMail", e.getMessage(), e);   
                } 

            }
        });

    }
}
```

gmail api open through this code

```
YOUR PACKAGE;

import javax.activation.DataHandler;   
import javax.activation.DataSource;   
import javax.mail.Message;   
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;   
import javax.mail.Session;   
import javax.mail.Transport;   
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;   
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;   
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;   
import java.io.IOException;   
import java.io.InputStream;   
import java.io.OutputStream;   
import java.security.Security;   
import java.util.Properties;   

public class GMailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator {   
    private String mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com";   
    private String user;   
    private String password;   
    private Session session;   

    static {   
        Security.addProvider(new com.provider.JSSEProvider());   
    }  

    public GMailSender(String user, String password) {   
        this.user = user;   
        this.password = password;   

        Properties props = new Properties();   
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");   
        props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);   
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",   
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");   
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");   

        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);   
    }   

    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {   
        return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);   
    }   

    public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) throws Exception {   
        try{
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);   
        DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));   
        message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));   
        message.setSubject(subject);   
        message.setDataHandler(handler);   
        if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)   
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));   
        else  
            message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));   
        Transport.send(message);   
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }   

    public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource {   
        private byte[] data;   
        private String type;   

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type) {   
            super();   
            this.data = data;   
            this.type = type;   
        }   

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data) {   
            super();   
            this.data = data;   
        }   

        public void setType(String type) {   
            this.type = type;   
        }   

        public String getContentType() {   
            if (type == null)   
                return "application/octet-stream";   
            else  
                return type;   
        }   

        public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {   
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);   
        }   

        public String getName() {   
            return "ByteArrayDataSource";   
        }   

        public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {   
            throw new IOException("Not Supported");   
        }   
    }   
}
```

JSSE Provider

```
import java.security.AccessController;
import java.security.Provider;

public final class JSSEProvider extends Provider {

    public JSSEProvider() {
        super("HarmonyJSSE", 1.0, "Harmony JSSE Provider");
        AccessController.doPrivileged(new java.security.PrivilegedAction<Void>() {
            public Void run() {
                put("SSLContext.TLS",
                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLContextImpl");
                put("Alg.Alias.SSLContext.TLSv1", "TLS");
                put("KeyManagerFactory.X509",
                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.KeyManagerFactoryImpl");
                put("TrustManagerFactory.X509",
                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerFactoryImpl");
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
}



 ADD 3 jars found in the following link to your Android Project (Right Click Project- add External Jars)

    mail.jar
    activation.jar
    additionnal.jar
```

Click here - How to add External Jars

Run the project and check your recipient mail account for the mail. Cheers!!

Hope this helps